# Using declaration contains unexpanded parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, using-declaration

How do I get this code to compile?

```
struct type1 {};
struct type2 {};

struct handler1
{
    void handle(type1){}
};

struct handler2
{
    void handle(type2){}
};

template <typename... Handlers>
struct TheHandler : Handlers...
{
    using Handlers::handle...; // DOESN'T COMPILE
};

TheHandler<handler1, handler2> handler;
handler.handle(type1());
```

Comment: [This works in C++17](https://godbolt.org/g/qoHVWq). It was added in C++17 (the `using` expanding parameter packs). It works there in C++14 as a compiler extension

Comment: @Justin Thanks but I'm stuck with C++14 for the time being.

Comment: As with all parameter pack expansions, you can rewrite this with recursion, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Yes, you can rewrite this with recursion as per the paper that proposed parameter-pack expansion with `using`: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0195r1.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`using` with parameter packs was added in C++17, so your code [would just work in C++17](https://godbolt.org/g/wm1bkn).

As a workaround for C++14, you can use recursion. [The proposal for `using...`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0195r1.html) shows how to do this:

```
template <typename Handler0, typename... Handlers>
struct TheHandler : Handler0, TheHandler<Handlers...>
{
    using Handler0::handle;
    using TheHandler<Handlers...>::handle;
};

template <typename Handler>
struct TheHandler<Handler> : Handler
{
    using Handler::handle;
};
```

<sup>[On Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/3SAohR)</sup>

It is possible to achieve logarithmic recursion depth, if you wish to do so.

Comment: And delegate the inheritance to a wrapper class if `TheHandler` shouldn't inherit `Handler0`

Comment: @PasserBy True, but I assumed it was fine as that's what it does in the question